# How do I find the closest distance of a on one path to a second path

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to python, numpy and Jupyter notebooks.

I have two CSV files containing a route in X,Y coordinates.

For each (X,Y) pair in dataset 1, I want to find the closest point and distance in the second dataset of (X,Y) coordinates.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I can load in the dataset and access the data to plot the two routes, but I'm having difficulty doing this next step.

Comment: I'll be honest and say that it does appear to do what I want to do, but I'm not sure how I access the columns of the dataframes in the example.

Comment: Try adding a little more detail to your question. Explain how you loaded the data (it sounds like you may have used Pandas `read_csv`, but I can't be sure). Tell us as specifically as you can which bit of the linked answer you're having trouble implementing in your instance.

Comment: How would I create the combined_x_y_arrays and points_list in the example you've provided from my two pandas dataframes, (Route1 the source coordinates, and Route2, the dataframe I want to find the closest point in)?

<pre>
    Route1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Route1.csv', header=None)
    Route2 = pd.read_csv('c:/Route2.csv', header=None)
<code>

Comment: Sorry, but I can't seem to get the code to format neatly.

Comment: `
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

points_1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1': np.arange(5), 'y1': np.arange(5)})
points_2 = pd.DataFrame({'x2': np.random.rand(5)*5, 'y2': np.random.rand(5)*5})

my_tree = KDTree(points_2)
dist, nearest_idx = my_tree.query(points_1)
nearest_point_2 = points_2.iloc[nearest_idx,:].reset_index(drop=True)
pd.concat([points_1, nearest_point_2], axis=1)
` - sorry, line breaks are wrong, but this is approximately what you want.

Comment: OK - so I have made some headway I think...
I have managed to get the dataframes to load, though for some reason I had to keep the 'points' as columns, where the example provided had the points as two rows.  Not sure what's going on there.
But now I have the index to the nearest point in the opposite list. 
More digging as I have to now find out how to calulate the distance.

Comment: The distance is returned when you run `my_tree.query(point_list)`. You get a tuple returned from that, the first element being the distance. So if you do `dist, idx = my_tree.query(point_list)` you get the two things you want.